# Intellij not importing SpringData Dependency from pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, spring-data

I am trying to use JPA repository from spring data, but the import is not working. I have the right dependency in pom.xml but Still the jar is not being loaded from maven. 
[image]

My pom.xml looks like this

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.bestbuy.supportspace</groupId>
<artifactId>video-library</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Video Library</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SERVLET -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--DATABASE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>VideoLibrary</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have looked into almost each and everything possible. The maven repository does have the artifact spring-data-jpa with release 1.2.2.Release, but still its not working

Comment: Do you have auto-import on? Did you re-import from the pom?

Comment: Yes Auto Import is on. Only "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

The dependency on spring-data-jpa is twice in your pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

try to remove one and check that 1.4.2 is your maven repo

Answer (score 0):

As Dave Newton mentioned - you should re-import the pom. Also, notice that `JpaRepository` is an interface, so you need to implement instead of extend.

[image]

Comment: I did re-import fro the pom, but nothing happens. A couple of developers apart from me have looked into this, but no one seems to find a solution

Comment: Try closing the IntelliJ, delete everything from m2 repository directory and then reimport the pom

Comment: I did that it did not work. Finally I had to remake the whole project again. And once I did that, added the dependency in the pom.xml. It immediately found the dependency and added it. I could not find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

try to set version directly in to dependency like this, instead of describe it as a propery.

```
<!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```